# How to print to http.ResponseWriter directly the json got from http.Get in Go?

Tags: json, http, go

This is my code:

```
func GetRepositories(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
   res, err := http.Get(fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", sconf.RegistryConf.url, sconf.RegistryConf.listrepo))
   if err != nil {
      w.WriteHeader(500)
      log.Errorf("Could not get repositories: %s", err)
      return
   }
  log.Info("Repositories returned")
  fmt.Fprintf(w, fmt.Sprintf("%v", res))

}
```

What I am trying to do is to directly print the same thing that appears when I access the URL inside `http.Get` which is in JSON format, but I am getting other things. How can I do this without umarshaling the JSON content form `http.Get` and then marshaling it and returning it?

Answer (score 2):

The [`http.Response`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response) returned by [`http.Get()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Get) is not just the (JSON) data sent by the server, it's a struct containing all other HTTP protocol related fields (e.g. HTTP status code, protocol version, header values etc). What you need to "forward" is only the `Response.Body` field which is an [`io.ReadCloser`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadCloser), so you can read the actual data from it sent by the server.

You may use [`io.Copy()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy) to copy the body from the response of `http.Get()` to your [`http.ResponseWriter`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter). Before that it's recommended to set the same content type that you get.

```
defer res.Body.Close()
if contentType := res.Header.Get("Content-Type"); contentType != "" {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", contentType)
}
if _, err := io.Copy(w, res.Body); err != nil {
    // Handle error
}
```